# PHP Site Generating Strange Pages

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a dynamic PHP based site and I've recently noticed its generating a lot of weird pages like this:
http://www.festivalsnap.com/festival/3151748-16th+Annual+Magnolia+Fest+/hotels/3151748-16th+Annual+Magnolia+Fest+/ticket/hotels

The site architecture should be like this www.mysite.com/festival/ and then there are 4 possible child pages for each event... /lineup /tickets /hotels /news

As you can see from the URL it just keeps creating more and more unwanted child pages. When I run a sitemap generator it will just keep going forever and creating more of these pointless pages.

It shouldn't go any deeper than the /hotels page but for some reason its just adding more and more child pages using any combination of the above pages.

I'm no good with PHP and my developer isnt being very helpful. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Edit:
The main event page comes from a file called festival.php and then there are 4 child pages under that - lineup.php tickets.php hotel.php and news.php that get variables from the event page (event title, dates, location, etc) and use it to search for tickets, hotels, etc.

I have noticed that I can tack on basically anything to the URL and it will add it in as part of the page title/event title. It looks like there is something weird going on with .htaccess

Here is the .htaccess code:
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.festivalsnap.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.festivalsnap.com/$1 [R=301,L]

```
RewriteRule festival/(.*)-(.*)/lineup$ lineup.php?eveid=$1&festival=$2
RewriteRule festival/(.*)-(.*)/news$ news.php?eveid=$1&festival=$2
RewriteRule festival/(.*)-(.*)/tickets$ ticket.php?eveid=$1&festival=$2
RewriteRule festival/(.*)-(.*)/hotels$ hotel.php?eveid=$1&festival=$2
RewriteRule festival/(.*)-(.*)/hotels/(.*)$ hotel.php?eveid=$1&festival=$2&hsort=$3
RewriteRule festival/(.*)-(.*)$ event_page.php?eveid=$1&festival=$2

RewriteRule artists/(.*)-(.*)$ artists.php?artid=$1&artname=$2
```

Comment: We won't be able to tell you much unless you post the code responsible...

Comment: can you show us what you have done?

Comment: I think its something weird with .htaccess so i've added that code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly something to do with your generator, and partly to do with .htaccess. The `.*` operator is extremely aggressive, so your .htaccess file says pretty much anything containing `festival/` with a hyphen somewhere later in the URL is a valid URL.

But that doesn't explain why your generator is "finding" all of those pages; there must be some bad links being created somewhere, either internally in the generator or in links on pages on your site.

Can you post some code?

**EDIT:** The .htaccess code should be much narrower - try replacing each of the occurrences of `(.*)` with `([^/]*)`.

As for the PHP, it's impossible to say exactly what is going on, but it sounds like the generator is finding those links on your site somewhere and following them, in which case the sitemap generator is working correctly, but your content has problems.  Check your logs, find one of the incorrect URLs, and see what page referred the user there. That will tell you where to look for the bad code.

Comment: I'd like to but I'm not really sure where to look or even which of those php files to look in. Do you have any better suggestions for .htaccess code? Ideally I'd like to get a 404 or a redirect if it goes any deeper than www.mysite.com/festival/event/hotels (or /tickets or whatever).

Comment: Also, the sitemap generator I'm using is just some generic one I bought online and not one that my developer created. Do you think if I had him build a custom one that would fix it?